# Oven Installation - Three prong outlet

Tags: appliances, installation, oven

I am looking to replace my old double oven since it has stopped working. It was plugged into the wall via a three prong outlet that is located above the cutout for the ovens in the back of the cabinet above. When reading about installing ovens it appears the standard is for ovens to be hardwired.

Since my house is setup for a 3 prong cord, would I remove the hardwire wiring and then run the 3 prong cord through the conduit and connect it to the oven that way? Is there a way to remove the hardwire wiring? Since the only pictures I can find are just stock photos of the oven it's hard to visualize how this will work.

EDIT: I added a picture of the plug, the old oven was a Whirlpool RBD275PDB and the new oven is a GE JKD3000SNSS. The power requirements for the old oven vs new oven are below:

KW Rating at 208V: New - 5.4, Old - 6.0

KW Rating at 240V: New - 7.2, Old - 8.2

Circuit Amps: New - 30, Old - 40

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are potentially other issues: Does the new oven have the same power requirements as the old oven? Often, newer ovens require more power, in which case you likely need not just a new breaker but new wire from the oven to the breaker. 3-wire (for US) is also generally obsolete, and now may be the time to upgrade it, particularly if you switch to hardwired connection or if you need a larger circuit. **Upload pictures of the existing receptacle and the oven breaker in your panel, plus model # of new oven.**

Comment: What make and model is your new oven? Also, can you post photos of the inside of the junction box for the oven receptacle?

Comment: 3-prongs aren't just obsolete, they're dangerous.  A perfectly routine problem with the neutral wire **will energize the chassis of the oven**.  I'd be keenly interested in if there is ground inside the junction box.    By the way hardwiring an oven is no big deal, so don't shy away from it merely because it's unfamiliar.

Comment: In my jurisdiction, hardwire is the only legal option for an oven.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I added a picture of the receptacle, model information, power requirements for new and old, and not sure where the oven breaker is in my panel since it isn't labeled but all the breakers look the same.

Comment: Upload a picture of your breaker panel.

Comment: There should be "40" molded into a double wide-breaker, or two single breakers tied together. There *might* be more than one 40A 240V circuit, but there should not be very many of those in the average house. If your panel veers "scary" it might just be two "40"s next to each other with no tie. In some arrangements this might be in a small panel right by the meter, if it's not on the panel inside the house.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I added a picture of the breaker panel, not sure which one goes to the oven.

Comment: You've only got one 40A double-breaker. So if things were installed correctly, that is for your oven. If it still partially works (e.g., control panel but not heat) then you can test by turning that breaker off. Or you can use a voltmeter to check at the receptacle. But this is interesting. You only have double breakers, all large. Looks like this might be used as a Rule of Six panel, with a subpanel somewhere connected to the 60A breaker. That subpanel could even be a small old panel. **Is there a main breaker in this panel (separate, typically at top or bottom)?**

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I couldn't find a main breaker anywhere. The breaker I have inside my house doesn't have a main breaker either from what I can see. The old oven was totally dead and is gone now so I won't be able to test it that way, looks like a voltmeter would be the way to check.

Comment: It sounds to me like the panel picture you uploaded is a Rule of Six == Maximum of six things that need to be turned off to shut off all power to the house in an emergency. In which case there *must* be a subpanel somewhere. That is not necessary for the oven project - it should be the 40A double-breaker in this panel - but it is important.

Comment: Can you post photos of the *inside* of the oven receptacle please? (Turn the oven breaker off and remove the screw in the center of the receptacle in order to get it apart)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an update and answer for anyone that comes across this looking for help. I turned off the breaker to the outlet, removed the outlet cover, removed the outlet hardware so there were just three wires (two hot, one ground). I added a junction box and wired the oven directly. As per the instructions with the oven, neutral and ground went to ground and one hot wire to each of the hot wires. Done and done, super simple.

Comment: Does this oven require only 208/240 V or does it require 120 V in addition? So does this oven need two line hots and a ground or does it require a neutral as well? This info should be in the installation instructions.

Comment: @JimStewart It's in the instructions. Only uses the 240 line and if you don't have a neutral line you plug it into the ground.